# Summation formula for Hermite polynomials

Tags: calculus, summation, quantum-mechanics, hermite-polynomials

It is a well-known identity that $$
2^{\frac n 2}H_n(x+y)=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} H_{n-k}(x\sqrt{2})H_k(y\sqrt{2})
$$
My question is whether something similar is known for
$$H_n(x+y)=\sum_{k=0}^n \sqrt{{n\choose k}} H_{n-k}(x\sqrt{2})H_k(y\sqrt{2})$$
I am interested in this because this would allow to evaluate sums of hermite functions which are solutions to the harmonic oscillator in quantum mechanics. Such a formula would then allow an easy transformation into relative coordinates, for example.

Comment: It is well known but do you know its the proof ? Of course no it won't work with a square root. Where does this formula come exactly ? It should give many clues (the differential equation for the Hermite polynomials tells us an inner product for which they are orthogonal, and the 1st identity is the expansion of $H_n(x+y)$ in this basis)

Comment: Could you expand your explanation with the first identity, maybe giving sources? Thanks

Comment: Wikipedia article on Hermite polynomials has that first identity listed there, for anyone looking for it.